# How to change a single value in a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After making some predictions through a supervised algorithm I put the results in a Dataframe then I export it to a CSV and this is what I get:

[image]

What I would like to do now is to simpy edit the very fist element of this column so that I get 0,0 instead of just  0. How can I do that? I cannot figure out how to do it in a easy way.

You can find below the code I used to get this:

```
df_MP_pred = pd.DataFrame(predictions) 
print(df_MP_pred.to_csv('testexportPREDTEMP.csv'))
```

Could you please help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A tip is always look at the params in the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add parameter `index_label=0` to [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df_MP_pred.to_csv('testexportPREDTEMP.csv', index_label=0)
```

Check:

```
df_MP_pred = pd.DataFrame({0:[1,2,3]})
print (df_MP_pred)
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3

print (df_MP_pred.to_csv(index_label=0))
0,0
0,1
1,2
2,3
```

Comment: If I do this I now get:

 19.125
19.125
19.0
19.0
19.0
19.125
19.25 

but I missing values and I do need the first element which is the 0 that I want to edit as such 0,0

Comment: That does not work. What should I do to remove the first element of the column (O) to only get 0,19.125
1,19.125
2,19.0
3,19.0
4,19.0
5,19.125
6,19.25

Comment: @Yannick - so need `df_MP_pred.to_csv('testexportPREDTEMP.csv', header=None)` ?

Comment: That's fine like this. Thanks for your much appreciated help.